# Does p:tagCloud have maximum strength?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tag-cloud

I am trying to use PrimeFaces tagcloud. However, once the strength goes over 6, the strength will be reset to 2. Here is my tagCloud.xhtml,

```
        <!--     <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" /> -->

        <p:tagCloud id="tagCloud" showDetail="true" model="#{tagsAdminBean.model}">
            <p:ajax event="select" update=":#{p:component('dialogForm')}"
                    listener="#{tagsDialogBean.onSelect}"
                    oncomplete="if (#{tagsDialogBean.showDialog}) {tagsDlg.show()}"></p:ajax>
        </p:tagCloud>
    </h:form>
```

Please see the tag cloud below. Tag-test1(6)'s strength is 6, and Custom Tag1's strength is 7, however, they are both reset back to 1 or 2. What am I missing?

[image: tagCloud image]

Comment: Where are they reset? I see 6 and 7 in the image

Comment: 6 and 7 are the number associated with the tag, and we use that number as strength. So I should put this way, once the strength is greater than 5, tags show as their strength as 2.

Comment: what I expected that tags with bigger number associated should show bigger size. Like in the image, Custom Tag1 should be biggest/

Comment: Please read the PrimeFaces docs for tagcloud. The answer is in there

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has. According to the [docs page 489](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#489), the maximum strength is 5

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, If the answer is good/helpful, it is good practice in StackOverflow to 'accept it'